# How to copy plots using right click in ggplot RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Is their a way I can copy the the box plots produced using the ggplot in RMarkdown and displayed in a chunk into word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right-click them and COPY IMAGE.

But you're likely to get better results by explicitly saving the image at the dimensions and resolution you intend to use.

```
library(ggplot2)

gg <- 
  ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(hp, mpg))

ggsave(
  file.path("output", "mtcars_hp-v-mpg.png"),
  plot = gg,
  width = 8.5 - 2, 
  height = (11 - 2) / 2, 
  units = "in",
  dpi = 300
)
```